# PHP: Date From Week Number In AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a work scheduler and want to page through the weekly calendars. I have the current week of the week and on the click of the left double arrow, I harvest the week number of the displayed week and send it to the controller with this script:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#navrow_prev', function(e){
        var curr_week = $('#display_week').text();
        var prev_week = parseInt(curr_week) - 1;
        $('#display_week').empty().text( prev_week );

        $.ajax({
            url:  "<?= site_url('ajax/get_monday_from_week'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: { week: prev_week },
            success: function(msg){
                //$('#display_monday').empty().text(msg);
                alert(msg);
            } // end success
        });
    });
})(); // end self-invoking anonymous function
```

The part before the ajax call works fine. However, I do not get an alert (I am looking for a response with which I can change the display dates of that week's monday and sunday ) and FireBug tells me I have a 500 error in the Controller function which is below. This is code I found from multiple Google searches and I don't understand where the error is.

```
public function get_monday_from_week(){
    $week = $this->input->post('week');
    $year = date('Y');
    if( (int)$week < 10){ $week = '0'.(string)$week; } else { $week = (string)$week; }

    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$week);
} // end get_monday_from_week function
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
```

UPDATE: I am now using this in the controller and getting one week later than I am expecting as a return. Did I screw up the code with my edit???

```
public function get_monday_from_week(){
    $week = $this->input->post('week');
    $year = date('Y');

    $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
    $day = date('w', $time);
    $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;

    echo date('Y-m-d', $time);
} // end get_monday_from_week function
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
```

I am currently posting a "46" (according to FireBug) and getting no response. ANY help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are getting 500 error, it is likely that your javascript has nothing to do with this (assuming of course you have verified that data is being send in AJAX request as expected). Have you tried to make the same exact request against your endpoint outside of a javascript context?

Comment: I get the generic Error 500 page. I am trying now to rewrite the AJAX Controller Function with Shuvo's code.

Comment: Have you first looked into server error logs to see what might be the cause of 500 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this one:

```
public function get_monday_from_week(){
    $week = $this->input->post('week');
    $year = date('Y');
    if( (int)$week < 10){ $week = '0'.(string)$week; } else { $week = (string)$week; }

    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$week)); // end parenthesis was missing
}// end get_monday_from_week function
```

Another one is:

```
function get_monday_from_week() {
    $week = 52;
    $year = 2013;
    $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
    $day = date('w', $time);
    $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
    $return[0] = date('Y-n-j', $time);
    echo $return[0];//2013-12-30

    if( (int)$week < 10){ $week = '0'.(string)$week; } else { $week = (string)$week; }
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$week)); //2013-12-23

     }
```

Comment: I modified this code to fit my app but the alert is ONE week too late. When I am moving from this week to last week, (from Week 47 to 46) and I am posting "46" (verified with FireBug), the alert is 2013-11-18 but it should be 2013-11-11. I edited my original question to show how I modified this code.